# Calculating centre of mass: what is wrong with my answer?

Tags: integration

I am really stressed because I cannot get the solution to a problem that I think I am doing right. It is to calculate the centre of mass of the solid defined by $0\le z\le 1$ and the projection onto the XY plane bounded by $ y = -x$ and $ x=y^2-2$. I set up a triple integral as follows, in the case for instance of the X coordinate:

$\iiint x  dzdxdy$, where

$0\le z\le 1$

$y^2-2\le x\le -y$

$-2\le y\le 1$

Doing this, I get $ -\frac 95$, and since the problem says the density is constant and mass is M, I just get that $x_{cm}=-\frac {9\rho}{5M} $.

I do something similar to get the others too, and they do not match the solutions in my book.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct but somewhat incomplete:

1. I checked your integral and the result $-9/5$ seems to be correct.
2. what is $\frac{\rho}{m}$? Density is $\rho=\frac{m}{V}$, where $V$ is the volume of the object. Therefore you can write $\frac{\rho}{m}=\frac{1}{V}$. The point is that you should be able to compute the volume of the object using an integral very similar to the ones you already computed. Putting that into your answer will yield just numbers not depending on any unknown constants.

Comment: Oh, okay, I see. I thought that since they just give me the constant values I was supposed to leave it as a function of them. I will get on it now. Thank you so much! This was giving me a headache.